# What is the easiest to backup a mongoDB deployed with mup?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I deployed my app on a Ubuntu server using `mup deploy` (https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) with the option `"setupMongo": true` in the mup.json file.

Everything works fine, and I would like to save the mongoDB database daily to FTP or S3, or to set a mongoDB replica to another server (to avoid copying the whole database every time, but it seems more complicated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is inspired by: 
[sheharyar.me/blog/regular-mongo-backups-using-cron](http://sheharyar.me/blog/regular-mongo-backups-using-cron)

It uses a script to: mongodump -> tar -> wput (ftp)

First, create a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

MONGO_DATABASE="your_db_name"
APP_NAME="your_app_name"

MONGO_HOST="127.0.0.1"
MONGO_PORT="27017"
TIMESTAMP=`date +%F-%H%M`
MONGODUMP_PATH="/usr/bin/mongodump"
BACKUPS_DIR="/home/username/backups/$APP_NAME"
BACKUP_NAME="$APP_NAME-$TIMESTAMP"

# mongo admin --eval "printjson(db.fsyncLock())"
# $MONGODUMP_PATH -h $MONGO_HOST:$MONGO_PORT -d $MONGO_DATABASE
$MONGODUMP_PATH -d $MONGO_DATABASE
# mongo admin --eval "printjson(db.fsyncUnlock())"

mkdir -p $BACKUPS_DIR
mv dump $BACKUP_NAME
tar -zcvf $BACKUPS_DIR/$BACKUP_NAME.tgz $BACKUP_NAME
rm -rf $BACKUP_NAME

wput $BACKUP_NAME.tgz ftp://login:password@ftp.domain.com/backups/
```

Save it as `mongo_backup.sh` and run:

```
chmod +x mongo_backup.sh
bash mongo_backup.sh
sudo su
crontab -e
```

And enter this new line:

```
00 00 * * * /bin/bash /home/username/scripts/mongo_backup.sh
```

That's it.

Answer (score 6):

If deployed with mup, you are in luck.
You can find the steps here: https://github.com/xpressabhi/mup-data-backup

Here are the steps again:

### MongoDB Data Backup deployed via mup

These commands run well only if meteor deployed with mup tool. Mup creates docker for mongodb hence taking backup becomes easy with these commands.

#### Backup

Take backup of running app data from docker then copy to local folder out of docker.

```
docker exec -it mongodb mongodump --archive=/root/mongodump.gz --gzip 
docker cp mongodb:/root/mongodump.gz mongodump_$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S).gz
```

#### Copy backup to server

Move data to another server/local machine or a backup location

```
scp /path/to/dumpfile root@serverip:/path/to/backup
```

#### Delete old data from meteor deployment

Get into mongo console running in docker then drop current database before getting new data.

```
docker exec -it mongodb mongo appName
db.runCommand( { dropDatabase: 1 } )
```

#### Restore data to meteor docker

```
docker cp /path/to/dumpfile mongodb:/root/mongodump.gz
docker exec -it mongodb mongorestore --archive=/root/mongodump.gz --gzip
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to mongodump it.

Assuming its running on the mup instance itself since it only listens to `127.0.0.1` you would have to ssh in and use `mongodump`.

If you simply run it:

```
mongodump
```

It will create a directory `dump` containing your backup.

If you want to do this remotely you would have to edit `/etc/mongodb.conf` to ensure it binds [globally](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/configuration/), you will have to create users though since it will be publicly accessible. Then set `auth` to true.

You could then `mongodump` from your own machine (you can download the mongodump binary from mongodb.org):

```
./mongodump --host <your server ip address> --username <username> --password <password>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Is there a way to do it automatically ? (for example every night)

Comment: @JeromeMartin You would have to write a cron. If the above (first bit of the answer works for you) you can use this to set one up: https://sheharyar.me/blog/regular-mongo-backups-using-cron/